# Access to public variable javascript in class

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript class which has three text variable:

```
myClasss = function(){
    this.color = "yellow";
    this.type = "car";
    this.other = this.type + ", " + this.color;
}
```

My class has an error.
How can I fill `this.Other` ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing semi-colon after the definition of the function it works.

```
myClasss = function() {
    this.color = "yellow";
    this.type = "car";
    this.other = this.type + ", " + this.color;
};
alert(new myClasss().other == "car, yellow");
```

[You can see it in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rDuz/)